# How do I get the user who wrote the bot command? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, disco

How do I get the user who wrote the bot command? So the author of the message.

Code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot wurde gestartet: ' + client.user.name)
#wts        
@client.command()
async def wts(ctx,name_schuh,preis,festpreis,url):
    channel = client.get_channel(693503741156130897)
    embed=discord.Embed(title="WTS", description= "@USER", color=0x00ff00)
    embed.add_field(name="**Sneaker:** ", value= name_schuh)
    embed.add_field(name="**Price:** ", value=preis)
    embed.add_field(name="**Negotiable:** ", value=festpreis)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url= url)
    await channel.send( embed = embed)
```

Comment: `ctx.author`? Otherwise please update your question to include the code you are working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ctx.author`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.author) will give you the [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) that sent the message.